# using autocorr for different matlab versions

Tags: matlab, correlation

I'm trying to compute the autocorrelation of my timeseries. This work on my laptop with matlab R2011a, but not on my desktop with matlab R2013a. I read somewhere that the Signal Processing Toolbox needs to be installed, and that is the case on both of my computers. There seems to be no function at all called autocorr, but I can find it again on the matworks documentation for 2014b. I have the same problem with xcorr, although matlab seems to recognize the function ('help xcorr' works, 'help autocorr' not).
How can I fix this?

Comment: autocorr is a function in Econometrics toolbox. xcorr is a function in Signal processing toolbox. To find autocorrelation of a signal x you can just call xcorr(x,x).

Comment: No need to call `xcorr(x,x)` - you can just call `xcorr(x)` to find the autocorrelation of `x`.

Comment: I know both of that, but it does not work, when I type xcorr(x) matlab responds with '??? Undefined function or method 'xcorr' for input arguments of type 'double'.'. And I have the Signal Processing Toolbox, but xcorr does not work

Comment: Are you sure you have the toolbox? There are 2 posible scenarios: 1) you dont have the toolbox (type `ver` in the commnand window to ensure that you have it). 2) You have already a variable with the name `xcorr`, therefore overwriting the function. Find that variable and call it somehow else, i.e. `myxcorr`

Comment: Just use `conv`, which isn't part of any toolbox. I think something like `conv(x,flipud(conj(x)))` will give you the same thing.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I already used 'ver`, so I have the toolbox for sure, and there is no variable calles xcorr.

Comment: If thats the case, then contact Matlab and report a bug, but I am skeptic....

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 The problem with `conv` is the efficiency. Try running it on a array of e.g. 2000000 elements and it'll take a long time to compute whereas `xcorr` finishes in few seconds.